# Randomness in linked lists

Tags: c++, data-structures, random

Can we get randomness in linked lists?. I'm implementing space shooter game in which enemies should shoot bullets randomly. I'm storing enemies in linked lists, I want to select some enemies randomly and shoot from them. How can I do this with linked lists?

Comment: You could just start from the first node and call n amount of " next " ...but there is probably a better way?

Comment: You mean calling 'next' random number of times every time? I'm thinking may be there is a better way.

Comment: My professor wants us to be familiar with linked lists, I'm in learning mode yet.

Comment: Switch to an array if you want to be able to index directly into your list. But you'll lose the ability to easily add/remove enemies. Otherwise it's as Sidar says, you'll have to pick a random number and traverse to it with `next`. If you need to use linked lists, you'll have O(N) index time. That's the trade off for easy add/remove.

Comment: It'd also be easy to implement a "Monte Carlo" (I think?) method in which each node has a probability. Normalize your probabilities so they're all between 0 and 1.0. Choose a random number between 0 and 1.0. If your first node's probability is < your random number, choose it. Otherwise decrement your random number by the probability and continue down the list until you get a probability < than your random number. EDIT: Now that I think about it, you can different distributions in Sidar's method just choosing one using random, no need for my method

Comment: Well, this is not really a game design related question. This is a linked list related question disguised as a game question. :)
Also, it has nothing to do with c++ or opengl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know precisely how many items are in your list, and how many you want to have shooting every frame, there's actually a relatively straightforward way of doing this: for each item, if there are *k* things left out of a list of *N*, and *p* items left to shoot out of a total of *Q*, then the current item should shoot with probability *p/k* - and then the values of *k* and *p* should be updated.  The pseudocode for this looks like:

```
myThing curThing = myList->head;
int objectsLeft = myListCount;
int shootersLeft = numShootersPerTick;
while ( curThing )
{
  if ( random(objectsLeft) < shootersLeft )
  {
    curThing->Shoot();
    shootersLeft--;
  }
  objectsLeft--;
  curThing = curThing->next;
}
```

Note that I'm assuming that random(N) returns a number between 0 and N-1 inclusive; i.e., one of N things.  While this algorithm seems like it should choose different items with different probabilities (after all, the check of a random number is changing for each item!), it can be shown mathematically that this not only chooses each individual shooter with the right probability, each set of shooters is actually equally likely.

Comment: +1 I'd like to see the math behind choosing a random number each iteration of the loop. It seems to me that this would actually reduce the chances of getting nodes at the end of the list. It's an interesting method.

Comment: @Byte56 The full case is more complicated (and can be found in chapter 3 of Knuth's _The Art Of Computer Programming_), but you can convince yourself in the case of 1 shooter that each item is equally likely: the first item is chosen with probability 1/N; then since the probability we don't choose the first element is (N-1)/N and the probability we choose the second element (if we get there) is 1/(N-1), the total probability the second element is chosen is ((N-1)/N)*(1/(N-1)) = 1/N, etc; all the way down to the last element with proability ((N-1)/N)*((N-2)/(N-1))*...*(2/3)*(1/2)*1 = 1/N.

Answer (score 4):

Randomizing a number N and then making ship N shoot is not the right way to go about this in my humble opinion. First, it means one ship will shoot every frame or every turn which is not necessarily what you are going for.

The problem with that being that no matter how many enemies are on the screen, the amount of shots fired will be the same. Weather you have 1 enemy or 100, the rate of fire coming from all enemies put together will be exactly one shot per turn/frame which makes no sense game design wise. It also means a ship may not fire for 2xN turns sometimes(this is kind of like the old martial art movies where the bad guys wait in line to fight with the 'hero' and never attack simultaneously).

The good way in my opinion would be to iterated over the ships and make each one fire with a certain probability, preferably based on the last time it fired.

```
long now = getCurrentTime... /*replace with real function*/
double epsilon = 0.0001; /*adjust as needed*/
while(current = enemyList.next()){
    if(Math.random() < epsilon * (now - current.lastFired))
    {
        current.fire();
        current.lastFired = now;
    }
}
```

There is hardly any point iterating over N elements if you don't use that opportunity. If you use a list it means you are planning to iterate over all the enemies and update each of them. No point in iterating again over N of them, just to pick one to fire.

Comment: @sum1stolemyname I don't follow

Answer (score 3):

You could just start from the first node and call n amount of " next ".

pseudo code:

```
int num = Math.random() * myLinkedList.Count;
for( num ){
     myLinkedList.next();
}
return myLinkedList.currentNode;
```

Perhaps you can add a second container like an array/arraylist/vector and manage it from there...You could always ask your professor if that's ok with him/her.

Comment: +1 clean and simple way to get a random item in a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to select **k** random elements from the list (**N** is the total number). These **k** elements selected should be completely random. The method is as follows:

1. Start by taking the first **k** elements.
2. Advance through the list; when presented with the **m-th** element, generating a random integer `0<=r<m`.

   - If `r<k`, throw out a random previously-chosen element and replace it with the **m-th** element.

A little arithmetic with probabilities and an inductive argument shows this gives all elements an equal chance.